# Fenchel transform of a indicator function

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

Let $X,Y$ two Banach spaces, $G:Y \to R\cup\{+\infty\}$ a convex l.s.c function and $A:dom(A)\subset X \to Y$ a linear closed (graph(A) is closed in $X\times Y$) linear operator.
Define 
\begin{eqnarray}
G_A(x,y) &=& G(y), \;\;if\;\;y=Ax \\
&=& +\infty,\;\; otherwise
\end{eqnarray}
and

\begin{equation}
\overline{G}(x,y)=G(y).
\end{equation}

So the fenchel transform is
\begin{eqnarray}
\overline{G}^*(x^*,y^*)&=& G^*(y^*) + \delta_0(x^*)\\
\delta_{graph(A)}^* &=& \delta_{graph(-A^*)},
\end{eqnarray}
where $\delta$ is the indicator function.

I am having a hard time to calculate the fenchel transform. I tried first the indicator function and I got this:
\begin{eqnarray}
\delta_{graph(A)}^*(x^*,y^*) &=& \sup_{(x,y) \in X\times Y}\{\langle (x,y), (x^*,y^*)\rangle - \delta_{graph(A)}(x,y)\} \\
&=& \sup_{(x,y) \in graph(A)}\{\langle (x,y), (x^*,y^*)\rangle\} \\
&=& \sup_{x \in dom(A)}\{\langle x, x^*+A^*y^*\rangle\},
\end{eqnarray} 
so, if $(x^*,y^*) \in graph(-A^*)$ then $\langle x, x^*+A^*y^*\rangle = 0$ and we have $\delta_{graph(A)}^*(x^*,y^*) = 0$, but if $(x^*,y^*) \notin graph(-A^*)$ why we are going to have $\delta_{graph(A)}^*(x^*,y^*) = \infty?$

And the first fenchel transform I did not understand the $\delta_0(x^*)$.